# Slide-out menu in iOS app (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, menu, slide, subview

I'm trying to build my own slide out menu in swift, but I'm having some troubles.
Now, I coded a function that change the view.frame.origin.x so that I got my view to slide on the right.
Now, I added a subview at index: 0 and I want to make it show when I slide the main view (content) out.

```
let navView: NavigationViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navView") as NavigationViewController

    view.insertSubview(navView.view, atIndex: 0)
    addChildViewController(navView)
    navView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

And that's what happen when I click on the menu logo (at the top-left corner):

```
    @IBAction func showMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("showMenu")
    if !self.menuIsOpen{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.x = 150
        }) { (isHappen: Bool) -> Void in
            if isHappen {
                println("OpenedUp!")
                self.menuIsOpen = true
            }
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.x = 0
            }) { (isHappen: Bool) -> Void in
                if isHappen {
                    println("Closed!")
                    self.menuIsOpen = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So, now, this works but I suppose that the subview slides together with the rest of the main view.
How can I make the navigationView not to hide? Or better, to stay there (I mean with the origin.x: 0)

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a navigation view, associated with a view controller (1), and then have the slide out menu view controller (2) inside that view controller (vc1.addSubview(vc2.view)?  Then you could just keep view controller (1)'s navigation bar up and the view controller (2) would be inside it so it does not slide view controller (1)'s navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but in case anyone else has the same problem: I've implemented a similar mechanic on an app I'm currently working on. To achieve it I used custom interactive transitions, which were introduced in iOS7. I would recommend checking out the following links:

- See *Custom Transitions Using View Controllers* https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/
- http://www.thinkandbuild.it/ios7-custom-transitions/ In this tutorial, the presented view is rotated to appear on screen; but it's not to much work to adapt the code to silde your menu in from the side and only fill part of the screen.
- http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/ This gives many examples of the kind of effects you can achieve using custom transitions.

Hope that helps.